# ahoy events Post error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, analytics, ahoy

I started code rails recently and I need to figure out this problem.

I use this function especially for my project. So i customize name and properties variables.

```
ahoy.track(name, properties);
```

In local there is no problem but in the live version when the tracking method runs i received  404 error. This line create A POST request to /ahoy/events and there is no path /ahoy/events in the live version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi everyone i try a lot and finally i found solution. Meanwhile [this issue](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy/issues/29) helped me a lot.

I modify only two files in my project.

**ahoy.rb**

```
  mattr_accessor :auto_mount
  self.auto_mount = false
```

**routes.rb**

```
mount Ahoy::Engine => "/ahoy", as: :my_ahoy
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ahoy routes get activated only when Ahoy.api is true. In config/initializers/ahoy.rb make sure to have

```
Ahoy.api = true
```

ref [here](https://www.jdeen.com/blog/upgrading-ahoy-analytics-routing-error-no-route)